# MC34063 - Stucks with too much parallel devices

Tags: buck

I've a circuit schematic:

[image]

[image]

I power my circuit using only PWR+ and PWR- at 24V.
When my power supply powers only one circuit or two, in parallel mode, I don't have any problem.
When I attach more like 3 circuits, sometimes at power ON all this circuits doesn't goes on.

I've measured voltage on PWR+ and PWR- when they stucks and all of them have 4.8V between PWR+ and PWR-. I've removed FUSE, D3 and V4 but nothing. Also reduced 100uF to 2.2uF and nothing.

I've supposed that if the voltage is too slow to rise on this device, it may stuck at certain point with a voltage at 4.7V (and output at 2v).

How I can solve or made immune this device to this behavior?

Also I can't understand how this device reduce my Vin from 24v to 4.8v, since I've 24V on my power supply instrumentation.

Comment: What are the  loads? what are the currents?

Comment: YOU are the only one who can explain why the 24v rail falls to 4.8V - YOU know what power supply YOU have used, whether is series R, what its current rating is etc. If you want to keep it secret, as you are doing now, we cannot help you. This is liable to be a major factor in your problem - maybe THE major factor. Why not give us all the details you have.  || Note that R26 limits your ability to drive a load. If you can afford to "blow up" an MC34063, try shorting out R26 (= 0 Ohms).

Comment: What power supply do you use?

Comment: You cannot get something from nothing.  You have PIN = 720mW.  As analog said **What are the loads? what are the currents?**  P=VI  If POUT > PIN, then the problem is explained.

Comment: Replace R10 with actual loads that fail.

Comment: Is 24V a current source of 30 uA or mA?  Meanwhile R10,25,27,28 alone draw 5.625 mA

Comment: Feed the cct with 24V at much higher current capability. What happens? || Why convert down to 5V to drive the OLED supplies? Why not convert from 24V directly with an appropriate IC? || V_OLED is 11.3V - easy to buck convert directly from 24V.

Comment: @Russell McMahon Well, the biggest problem of this forum is that there's never enough information in users post. I've 5 sheets of my schematic but they will not add additional information, since what happen is outside of them and related to buck regulator. I can tell there's an MCU, some LED, bunch of CAPs, 500mA max load on MC34063 and 4.5v out. At 24V I've 0.030A, as said, when I power MC34, that's all. If I know what is happen and I know what can be, I will not post on this forum. Maybe?

Comment: It's feed from a laboratory instrumentation, I've powered much higher load with them. || Not related to my question, it's part of power schematics. Not developed by me. || Of course, as I said, my question is clear and specific. BC34063 goes in a stuck situation during a particular situation and generate me another particular situation. Someone with experience with BC34063 had this problem? Someone have idea on how to make this IC more robust to this situation?

Comment: @Singed OK. If you selectively choose what to answer or respond to the outcome is not likely to be good. Sadly, you do not wish to cooperate and insist that your input is "clear and specific". | Did you TRY shorting R26 as I suggested (twice)? Presumably you do not count my hundreds of thousands of device as "experience".

Answer (score 1):

I have produced several hundred thousand products using MC34063 or equivalent.
I am "familiar with its operation."
However, YOU have not given us enough information for us to be sure what your problem is.

The biggest problem is approximately what you say BUT from "the tone of voice" that comes across it sounds as though you think this is the "fault" of the people answering the questions :-) :-(. I and many others (not all) are eager to help BUT if people who ask questions decide to defend their approach rather than trying to help the people trying to help them it generally leads to worse outcomes than otherwise.

People ASKING QUESTIONS are **not** expected to provide copious amounts of trivia, BUT it is common, as in this case, for those who ask to not provide data which is available to them and clearly relevant. eg

- You have not said what power you wish to provide per load device, or how many load devices you wish to drive  - these are utterly crucial factors and you cannot hope to design a circuit without such information. Neither can we.
- You have NOT said what the supply CAN provide at 24V - only what
  (apparently) it DOES supply in this case.
- I suggested that you
  short R26 - have you done so?
- What is the current rating of your 220 uH inductor.
- Please provide brand model datasheet link.
- Your timing capacitor on pin 3 / Tc is VERY small for this IC.
  It puts Osc_freq at the top end of its range at around 100 kHz.
  Why?
- What frequency do you see? 
  What ton and toff.
- At 24V in and 5v out your toff needs to be about 5 x
  ton. This may be a problem.

Others have asked questions.
You have answered some.
You originally said 30 uA and now say 30 mA and,
we still do not know what current the supply **can** supply before it
current limits at 24V.

Help us help you if you want help.

Comment: This could be a good comment to ask me additional information. My tone was just a result to your tone on your first answer . Accusing tone, to somebody that ask consulting and help, it's a wrong approach. Think about if someone pays you for a question and you act like this? It's quite sure that it'll go to another professionist. Maybe SE should add (and there's) PUT ON HOLD option where people ask more informations (point by point). In other way, just don't answer if not able or possible. StackExchange has grown, but seems that a lot of angry people comes with. Not good approach for a teacher.